# I'd like to be together two send mail tasks ssis

Tags: ssis, sendmail

I have used ssis 2008. My boss require to bring  two send mail tasks together as one.

One send mail tasks exists at event handler of OnError. Another one exists at event handler of OnPostExecute. My boss tell me the contents of From, To, contents of mail are same, So let's bring them together as one.

At first, I suggest to use variables. However, these two exists different packages each other. So my boss just want to know SSIS has the function to manage these two send mail tasks.

I don't know the way, so I asked with it here.
If you have some idea, Please tell me.

Comment: Why not just delete one of them, if they are sending the same email?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have two SSIS packages.  One is applying a Send Mail task on the OnError event and the other package has a Send Mail task on the OnPostExecute event?  Since both Send Mail tasks are applying the same information for the SmtpConnection, From, To, Cc, BCc, Subject, MessageSourceType, MessageSource, Priority and Attachments, these need to read from a single source.

In this case, you have a couple of options:

1. Store the details for each of the Mail components in a database table.  Read this information from the table into variables of the SSIS package and then apply Expressions in the Send Mail Task Editor to populate using those variables.  This means you'll need to add a SQL Task in the Event Handler to capture the information from the database before each Send Mail task.

   [image]
2. Set up Parameters for each SSIS package for the mail components and again apply variables and expressions as in option 1 to populate the Mail Task items.

My recommendation is the apply option #1.  Here you can update who receives the emails and so forth in the database without having to update the package.  Even if you are applying a Send Mail Task for the OnError and OnPostExecute event handlers in both packages, option #1 still works the best and is easy to implement.

Please let me know if this helped.

Comment: I suggest your idea today. However my boss stunning not accept the idea. Sorry I may ask different question later

Comment: You may need to also explain to your boss that each Event handler requires its own Send Mail Task, you cannot apply one Send Mail Task for multiple Event Handlers.  The option I provided is the most direct for achieving your goals.  Otherwise, you could apply a Script Task instead as in the following link:  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic451275-148-1.aspx

Comment: If your boss knows how to implement what they have in mind, then they should share it with you.

Comment: Thank you for more comments and apologize for response late.
My boss changed the system flow on Friday. So the mail task method is changed. I wonder why my boss required the task. 
I'm sorry to bother

Comment: No problem, that happens frequently in IT.  Could you provide a vote up indicating the answer would have addressed the issue?  Thanks.